# atlcom.h build error when built for platform set to x64

Tags: visual-c++, 64-bit, atl

I am converting a existing c++ project to 64-bit version from 32-bit version. This project builds fine in 32-bit version, after converting to build for x64 platform in Configuration Manager i am getting bellow build error, are there any specific i have to inherit for 64-bit version or am i missing anything.

**error C2259: 'ATL::CComObject' : cannot instantiate abstract class
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h**

Below is the error from the output while building the project.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(2000): error C2259: 'ATL::CComObject<Base>' : cannot instantiate abstract class
          with
          [
              Base=NAlertBand
          ]
          due to following members:
         'HRESULT IContextMenu::GetCommandString(UINT_PTR,UINT,UINT *,CHAR *,UINT)' : is abstract
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\shobjidl.h(2732) : see declaration of 'IContextMenu::GetCommandString'
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(1989) : while compiling class template member function 'HRESULT ATL::CComCreator<T1>::CreateInstance(void *,const IID &,LPVOID *)'
          with
          [
              T1=ATL::CComObject<NAlertBand>
          ]
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(2096) : see reference to function template instantiation 'HRESULT ATL::CComCreator<T1>::CreateInstance(void *,const IID &,LPVOID *)' being compiled
          with
          [
              T1=ATL::CComObject<NAlertBand>
          ]
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(2095) : see reference to class template instantiation 'ATL::CComCreator<T1>' being compiled
          with
          [
              T1=ATL::CComObject<NAlertBand>
          ]
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(2091) : while compiling class template member function 'HRESULT ATL::CComCreator2<T1,T2>::CreateInstance(void *,const IID &,LPVOID *)'
          with
          [
              T1=ATL::CComCreator<ATL::CComObject<NAlertBand>>,
              T2=ATL::CComFailCreator<-2147221232>
          ]
          NAlerts.cxx(44) : see reference to function template instantiation 'HRESULT ATL::CComCreator2<T1,T2>::CreateInstance(void *,const IID &,LPVOID *)' being compiled
          with
          [
              T1=ATL::CComCreator<ATL::CComObject<NAlertBand>>,
              T2=ATL::CComFailCreator<-2147221232>
          ]
          NAlerts.cxx(44) : see reference to class template instantiation 'ATL::CComCreator2<T1,T2>' being compiled
          with
          [
              T1=ATL::CComCreator<ATL::CComObject<NAlertBand>>,
              T2=ATL::CComFailCreator<-2147221232>
          ]
  QMessage.cxx
```

Thanks

Comment: Post the part of your code that implements actual `NAlertBand::GetCommandString`. The problem is that its parameters do not match what they are supposed to match. In Win32 the match by incidence, and this does not happen in x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a similar thread - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/d6144eaa-fa37-4133-87a0-75a06633209b

Please post the rest of the errors also.

Comment: After Changing the first parameter type of GetCommandString from UINT to UINT_PTR, i was able to build the application fine both in 64-bit and 32-bit.